# Converting Silverlight 4 InkPresenter omits uploaded images when converted to WriteableBitmap

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I have a web application that incorporates a Silverlight drawing pad. The strokes are saved as XAML in a database. Additionally, any text or moveableimage objects are also saved in the XAML. The moveableimage objects have as their source images being served from the same server and same domain as the Silverlight application.

In order to perform a scale up on the sketch pad contents, I use a WriteableBitmap:

```
            ScaleTransform transform = new ScaleTransform();
            transform.ScaleX = (double)10;
            transform.ScaleY = (double)10;

            WriteableBitmap fullSizeBinary = new WriteableBitmap(workCanvas, transform);
            string fullSizeBinaryString = XamlHelper.GetBase64Jpg(fullSizeBinary);
```

XamlHelper is a custom class using ImageTools to convert the WriteableBitmap to JPEG. I have tried with and without the transform. The WriteableBitmap omits the child moveableimage objects and the resulting JPEG has all the strokes and text objects, but the moveableimage objects do not render. I have tried a variety of things thinking it was security, memory, distinct controller paths, etc. Nothing. Been banging my head against this for hours and I can't figure it out.

When the method containing the above code is invoked by the user clicking a button inside the Silverlight application, it works perfectly. When the method containing the above code is invoked programmatically (i.e., through a parameter passed into the Silverlight application from an MVC controller) it doesn't work.

Comment: What are you passing in an how? Is it a matter of control state not being initialized?

Comment: That's a good question. I actually have the controller load up the view with Silverlight. A series of calls between the Silverlight app and the web service loads the XAML data into the InkPresenter (the workCanvas object seen above). The strokes and jpg/png images (i.e., the MoveableImage objects) load great, just as the user had put them in when sketching. Everything looks like it's working. Except that when it saves, the jpg/png MoveableObjects are not saved as part of the rasterized image. This has been headbangingly dumbfounding to say the least.

Comment: so you load to your InkPresenter, all looks good, get your writeable bitmap, get your jpg image - and the strokes are missing?

Comment: Almost: load InkPresenter, everything looks good, get my writeable bitmap, get my jpg image - and the jpgs/pngs added to the InkPresenter are missing. Strokes and text are there.